# Margin-Top Not Working on Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, browser

I have a very frustrating error that only exhibits itself on my Android and iOS browsers (the standard ones and the Firefox app).

My simple HTML ensures a div will stay at the top of the page as the user scrolls. This is achieved by detecting the scroll event and setting the div's `margin-top`. This is for a Parallax scrolling website. *Yes I know I can use `fixed` but fixing changes the dimensions of the div and makes content below the div 'popup' vertically. I will explain in detail why fixed is not an option below.*

If you run this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k78mse4p/1/) it works on desktop browsers but not on Mobile

The HTML works fine across Desktop browsers but on Android and iOS browsers the div does not remain fixed. Do you know what is going wrong and how I get this to work on Mobile browsers aswell?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no'>
    <title>Preview</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <style>
        #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 900px;
            height: 1500px;
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        .fixed-slide {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body> 

    <!-- Header Static content here -->

    <div id="container">
        <div class="fixed-slide">
            <p>Foo Bar</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Lots of Static main page content here. If I were to make .fixed-slide fixed this content would now popup 
                and appear underneath the header content - naughty - not to mention that .fixed-slides dimensions
                will change. Thus the need for margin-top instead -->

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var CONTAINER_TOP = $("#container").offset().top;
            var FIXED_SLIDE = $('.fixed-slide').first();

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var marginTop = scrollTop - CONTAINER_TOP;

                if (marginTop < 0 || marginTop > ($("#container").height() - FIXED_SLIDE.height()))
                return;

                FIXED_SLIDE.css('margin-top', marginTop);
            });
        });

    </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

The div sits between static content (above and below it). If it gets set to fixed then the content below will pop up and the div sits ontop of it. And the div has its dimensions specified as percentages so when fixed it not longer takes up 100% of its parent containers width but 100% of the window width. Thus fixed is not going to work here unless I do a lot more work.

Comment: I am not getting yet, but is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k78mse4p/3/) what you want?

Comment: @divy3993 As I explained making it fixed changes the divs dimensions. I editted your JSFiddle to show the problem better: https://jsfiddle.net/k78mse4p/4/